# R: Saving the Output of "dput" in a txt File

Tags: r, txt, notepad

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
id = 1:10
var_1 = rnorm(10,10,10)
var_2 = rnorm(10,10,10)
data_1 = data.frame(id, var_1, var_2)
```

If I use the "dput" statement in R, I get the following output:

```
 dput(data_1)

structure(list(id = 1:10, var_1 = c(8.82195120774659, -3.93182446227049, 
4.71778269084519, 1.75623141174446, 8.04018019946558, 24.512930378032, 
18.5285862803682, 14.0274634385899, 13.2841577275347, 15.2732721877118
), var_2 = c(29.6332731622598, 22.5632323327142, -8.9690858260254, 
-7.20867402757854, -0.040059695538643, 0.727780887727967, 27.3854470138422, 
5.04872507031284, 0.934424948207598, 17.6628276038318)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I can then manually copy/paste this output into a notepad/txt file:

[image]

But now, suppose my file is much bigger:

```
id = 1:100000
var_1 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
var_2 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
data_2 = data.frame(id, var_1, var_2)
```

When I write `dput(data_2)` the output is too big to manually copy/paste into notepad.

I tried the following idea:

```
attempt = capture.output(dput(final))
saveRDS(attempt,"attempt.RDS")
```

I then tried to open "attempt.RDS" in notepad, but I get the following output:

```
¤,f®îMáVá1·²-×H*Ç3·†§F#ÉÛx·FR?H@z
$÷^pk±Ö4’¶RÕè=H®ô; ¯OÒ»Iûi¤äV  ²ÙêÂÔÖ§@º  5’ÊñÌ­çdn=ç¶FRÃ:4’zr HoäjŠn…o®‘TŽ¯W Ý–$w5’öÓ   H?"I$µˆ)©«¥:¯¹ÒJ<s~
j4’jsÜ‹äêi³½0™[ý~Dô:$4’ø"¦U_‡$š4’Ü³íVM3¥;4’zré É­AoQ¼ÐHZÆÌÕ•hn];skÅs¤r|½   H?É•Ý
êJp·ŽžÍVÓ§¶uUIy¼nÒHjËw;wkôSHyL«é$ì”8¥
¤eL«Þ›Ä:4’zré‰;[¿éuH"h$‰EL«é~$YÔH*Çsç¦F#©6Ç½H
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the output of `dput` in the text file directly without manually copy-pasting it. For example, with `mtcars` dataset you can do -

```
dput(mtcars, 'new_file.txt')
```

This will save the output of `dput` in the file called `new_file.txt` in your working directory.